# Jquery UI selectable - change dom obeject which fired selected / unselected event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a huge set of selectable obejcts.

You can click them and then their id is added to a form, when they are deselected it's removed from the form again.

I had a working version, till i noticed that sometimes if you click too fast the id is added multiple times.

For prohibiting this i added a class to the list item so that it is classified as processing.

**My Question:**

How do i get a pointer to the DOM Element which was clicked in order to add the class

What works to run over all "selected" but that results in other problems:

```
$( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
 if($(this).hasClass('processing'))
 return;
 $(this).addClass('processing');
 });
```

What I have now - to only get the element firing the event... is wrong:

```
 $(".selectgroup").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.metaKey = true;

   }).selectable( {filter: "li"},
        {
            stop: function(){
                // Add to Form
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('processing'))
                return;
                $(this).addClass('processing');

                var itemid = $(this).attr("value");
                var formhtml ='<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" id="id'+itemid+'" value="'+itemid+'">';
                $("#tagform").append(formhtml);
                });
         },
        {
             unselected: function( event, ui ) {

                itemid = "#id" + ui.unselected.value;
                $('').removeClass('processing');
                alert(itemid);
                $(itemid).remove();
             }
        }.................................
```

For somebody who is fit in jquery this must be very easy to solve.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, Do you want the selected element?

Comment: yep i want to add the class processing to the element which was selected, to prohibit multiple execution of adding my hidden input field

Comment: So why don't you use `selected` event and add the class to the element?

Comment: i did in a test the only thing different is the them when event is called, stopped should be also called after selection. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Selectable#events , don't know if i makes a different in my scenario i still only have event and ui and in event must be the point

Comment: What I understood from your reply is you need to remove the class after performing some action on the selected element. and allow further selection on the same element. is it right?

Comment: yes 1. selected event add input to form 2. on deselect remove input

To enshure that it can only be added 1 time to the form add / remove class processing. 

Cause i figured out that i you click to often it will result in multiple inputs

Comment: Why don't you set a global var on `selected` event and remove class from that element after your processing is done?

Comment: selected: function( event, ui ) {}

Comment: Guys: The Simple question is how can i access the element which fired the event, can't be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question.

When you now it, it's pretty easy.

See and save yourself some time:

```
        {
            selected: function(event,ui){
                // Add to Form
                var item = $(ui.selected);

                if(item.hasClass('processing')){
                  alert("return");  
                  return;
                }
                item.addClass('processing');

                var itemid = item.attr("value");
                alert("S ID - " + itemid);
                var formhtml ='<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" id="id'+itemid+'" value="'+itemid+'">';
                $("#tagform").append(formhtml);



            }
        },
        {
             unselected: function( event, ui ) {

                itemid = "#id" + ui.unselected.value;
                $(ui.unselected).removeClass('processing');
                alert(itemid);
                $(itemid).remove();
             }
```